# Can we compare a row value with another row value in the table and highlight it in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table where 3 columns can have same value

Example:

```
Name Score_a Score_b Score_c
A    12       15     18
B    3        3       3
C    20      25       30
```

I want to highlight ( with a colour ) the row B since all the three scores are same.

I am unable to do it with conditional formatting available.
Can something be worked out using DAX? Please help!

Comment: You can't use conditional format or you have problems figuring out how to using to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried doing it with basic conditional formatting available in Power BI and could not achieve it from that and hence I am exploring DAX to solve this challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, first create a measure using the following dax formula:

```
Measure = 
IF( 
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Score_a] ) = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Score_b] ) && 
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Score_b] ) = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Score_c] ), 1, 0
)
```

Then you need to use conditional format on every column that you want to highlight and select the Measure you created.

[image]

This is the result

[image]

Comment: This should work. Alternatively the color can be also define directly in place of 0 and 1.

Comment: this works like charm!! thank you so much. I have upvoted :)

Comment: this works like charm!! thank you so much. I have upvoted :)